# "Place" a WinForm directly on the desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, overlay, desktop

So I want to have something similar to an desktop overlay. So the thing is I tried to draw to the desktop wallpaper directly but this will get redrawn and from what I read there is really no good way around this. So I tried to go with a broderless completely transparent WinForm with text on it.

The Problem I have with is that hitting <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will hide the application and I didn't found a way to prevent this or bring it up again. Also I read that setting the form as a Child of the Desktop can cause problems aswell.

What I did so far was setting the position of the Form directly above the Desktop:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
const UInt32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;

//By calling SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE); it will move to the very back of all windows.
```

What I want in the end is a Win Form that is always ontop of the Desktop but under every other window.

Comment: There is no documented way to do this, Microsoft does not like making this easy.  But it is hackable by pinvoking FindWindowEx() to find a window named "Progman", FindWindowEx() again to find its child window named "SHELLDLL_DefView", SetParent() to glue your window to it.  It does void the warranty multiple ways, not something that I would want to support.  Google "windows forms replace desktop window" to find people that are more courageous than me.

Comment: I will look into that a bit later thanks a lot!

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot it works like a charm!

Answer (score -2):

You should run a thread which in fraction of time ( such as 100ms) call `BringWindowToTop` api and bring your window aplication to top, it will solve to  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> issue.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool BringWindowToTop(HandleRef hWnd);
```